# Updating table on test SQL Server database from live environment with a query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I need to update a few tables on test environment from our production database. Basically it's the same table, just a few months more recent.

So, here's a query that I'm trying to implement:

```
UPDATE [Server-DEV].[Database].[dbo].[bHRRM] 
SET [Field1] = b.[Field1], 
    [Field2] = b.[Field2], ... ,
    [FieldX] = b.[FieldX]
FROM [Server-PROD].[Database].[dbo].[bHRRM] AS b
```

I don't care about data being overwritten, as it's the same. Even opposite is true - if there's a difference, test server better to update accordingly. But I don't want duplicates.

Now, there's a problem with a `KeyID` column, if it's included. And even if I'm excluding it from the `SET` - there's still an error:

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.bHRRM' with unique
> index 'biHRRM'. The duplicate key value is (5, 1000).

So, first question here is - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need at least one field to do equality between the tables. Right now it is performing a Cartesian product that is, updating each row from prod to all rows in test over and over.

Comment: Also I would strongly recommend you to reconfigure this access patterns in your Database. **Having WRITE access to both production and test under the same connection is a recipe to disaster awaiting to happen**. You should either use some sort of replication strategy or have a reader only connection for production when connecting to the DEV one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem I see right now is there is **nothing** in the update query to correlate the PROD server data with the DEV server data. It's not enough for the two tables to have the same schema and key definitions: you need an explicit correlation as part of the `UPDATE` statement.

This means it's trying to set the values from *every row* in production to *every row* in dev. That's gonna be **slow**, but even more to the point: it's gonna create duplicates at various points.

What should work is this:

```
UPDATE dev
SET [Field1] = prod.[Field1], 
    [Field2] = prod.[Field2], ... ,
    [FieldX] = prod.[FieldX]
FROM [Server-PROD].[Database].[dbo].[bHRRM] AS prod
INNER JOIN [Server-DEV].[Database].[dbo].[bHRRM] dev on dev.KeyID = prod.KeyID
```

Alternatively, if this is some kind of full-refresh from production you might consider just dropping the DEV table to fully replace it (via `SELECT INTO`). (This will also mean redefining any indexes/triggers/etc). Or you could `TRUNCATE` the DEV table to efficiently remove *all* of the records but preserve the structure, then do an `INSERT ... SELECT` with no `WHERE` to repopulate data from production.

Of course, if it's not a full refresh these options could remove important older rows and insert new rows you don't want (and then just the `UPDATE` query shown is enough). But if it is, this also takes care of those operations to either simplify the old process or cover something that was previously missed.

Comment: This answer beat my comment by a few seconds :)